# How to create customized calendar

Tags: android-widget, android, android-calendar

I want to create a customized calendar.
It should look like this:

[image: calendar]

Please help me make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a screenshot of [the `DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I big fan of you.